# Show that $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N^*}}\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}A_n$ given that $A_k\subseteq A_{k+1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

Let $\mathbb{N^*}=\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$

Given that $A_k\subseteq A_{k+1}$ $\forall k\in\mathbb{N^*}$

Show that

$$\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N^*}}\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}A_n $$

How could I prove the equality?

---

On part (a) of the same problem I've proven that
$$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N^*}}\left(\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}A_n $$
By proving that $\displaystyle A_n=\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k$ (by induction on $k$ using  $\displaystyle x\in A_k\implies x\in A_{k+1}$) so I was thinkin of doing something similar by letting $\displaystyle \bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k=B_n$ but I'm stuck.

Comment: Just extra info which may give some insight: if $x$ is an element of the set on the left side, then that means that "$x\in A_k$ for infinitely many $k$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ the LHS and $B$ be the RHS. For each $n$,
$$
\bigcup_{k\ge n} A_k \subset B
$$
so that
$$
A=\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k\subset B
$$

Conversely, let $x\in B$. Then $x\in A_n$ for some $n$, so $x\in A_k$ for every $k\ge n$ by your assumption, so $x\in A$.